DDIA doctor on-call example, Repeatable Read with lock VS Serializable
Background

You are writing an application for doctors to manage their on-call shifts at a hospital. The hospital usually tries to have several doctors on call at any one time, but it absolutely must have at least one doctor on call.

In the context of the Repeatable Read isolation level, here’s how the process works:

In each transaction, your application first checks that two or more doctors are currently on call; if yes, it assumes it’s safe for one doctor to go off call. Since the database is using snapshot isolation, both checks return 2, so both transactions proceed to the next stage. Alice updates her own record to take herself off call, and Bob updates his own record likewise. Both transactions commit, and now no doctor is on call. Your requirement of having at least one doctor on call has been violated.

Author suggests:

If you can’t use a serializable isolation level, the second-best option in this case is probably to explicitly lock the rows that the transaction depends on.

Question
I understand that the author states that MySQL and PostgreSQL’s Repeatable Read level cannot detect lost updates, whereas Serializable can. The author believes that Serializable is superior to Repeatable Read with locks.
I have a different perspective. For MySQL, I believe it is more efficient to use RR with locks rather than Serializable. This is because MySQL implements Serializable using Two-Phase Locking, which has poor performance. And this method gives flexibility, you can use lock when you need, at the rest of the time, you can enjoy the high performance that RR brings.
On the other hand, for PostgreSQL, using Serializable is indeed the best choice because it implements Serializable using Serializable Snapshot Isolation, which offers good performance.
Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?
I have asked a guy who proficient in backend, he say this is not because you can change the isolation level at any time.
Thank you in advance! :)
